# Use custom.ini with Grafana

Tags: customization, grafana

I'm trying to use a customisation file (**custom.ini**) for my Grafana installation. Unfortunately this isn't working.

What I have done:

1. Installed a VM with CentOS 7
2. Added the Grafana Yum Repo as described in the [official documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/rpm/)
3. Installed Grafana with

   `yum install grafana`
4. Then I created a simple customisation file

   `vi /etc/grafana/custom.ini`
5. With this content

   `default_theme = light`
6. Restarted Grafana

   `systemctl restart grafana-server`

Unfortunately the theme has not changed from dark to light.

If I uncomment the same line in the `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` then it is working correctly.

Any suggestions? Many Thanks

Comment: Do you have `default_theme` under section `[users]` ? Or did you set a section at all in the `custom.ini`?

Comment: No I forget it. I defined it now but also with the section `[users]` it isn't working. It seems, that the `custom.ini` is ignored at all.

Comment: Can you please hit  `ps aux` and show the line for Grafana.. or in `/etc/init.d/grafana` there must be parameters for the config path. Maybe custom.ini is not included at all.

Comment: @DanFromGermany the parameter is `/usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`, also the `custom.ini` is not called at all. In the [documentation](http://docs.grafana.org/installation/configuration/), if I understand it correctly, there is not need to define it.

Comment: Make sure there is no `;` before any configuration. In doubt, I'd just use the grafana.ini for configuration, no need to put it in custom.ini I guess. Or try to append `--config /etc/grafana/custom.ini` in the init.d script but this could be overwritten on update.

Comment: There is no `;` before the field. With `grafana.ini` is working fine. But in some cases is better with `custom.ini` to separate the modifications from the original `.ini`. It seems to be a bug...

Comment: What version of grafana are you running?

Comment: @OluwafemiSule hi, i think it was 5.1.3. Now I am running the latest version 5.3.2 but I didn't try it anymore with the custom.ini

Comment: two things: can you get it to work by just changing the `grafana.ini` file instead of creating a `custom.ini`? also you could try to just manually provide the config file location using the `--config PATH/TO/CONFIG` flag

Comment: hi @4UmNinja thanks for the feedback. Yes, if I change the settings directly in the grafana.ini it is working correctly.

Comment: assuming the `path/to/grafana.ini` is where you also have your `custom.ini` and you don't have another file overriding that like `default.ini` than that's strange. could it be because you're not initializing from a default state eg: like creating new admin user?

Comment: same issue for me,  when using grafana image and docker. Strange

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ...the parameter is `/usr/sbin/grafana-server --config=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`, also the `custom.ini` is not called at all. ...

You were correct at this point in your comments: a `custom.ini` file is simply not used. The `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` file is the custom config file for your platform (Yum repo = rpm package).

See [this comment](https://github.com/grafana/grafana/issues/2616#issuecomment-135748609) by Grafana co-founder and the note in [this docs section](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/configuration/#config-file-locations).

Comment: So, if I understood it correctly, the custom.ini overrides the grafana.ini only if Grafana is installed manually. Otherwiese, with a rpm installation (like mine), you can only choose one ini file to be loaded.

Comment: The Windows version, for example, uses a custom.ini file. It's the deb/rpm packages in particular - they start the grafana service with only one config file specified.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
You can either use `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` as Suggested by @patricktokeeffe.

However I found another possible solution:

On my machine the systemd unit file (`/lib/systemd/system/grafana-server.service`) had:

```
# ...
[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/default/grafana-server
# ...
ExecStart=/usr/bin/grafana-server \
  --config=${CONF_FILE}
# ...
```

From that I isnpected the env file `/etc/default/grafana-server` that had the line in it:

```
CONF_FILE=/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
```

I checked, and the default `grafana.ini` did not have any relevant config that I would lose, so I changed the line to point to my `custom.ini`, and lo and behold, it had workedth.

**IMPORTANT**:
This works on `deb` installations (like debian or ubuntu), so one would need to check it on `rpm` installations too. Also, the unit file might be elsewhere, but `systemctl status ...` shows where it is.